# Array Sorting with Integers and Characters

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort two different kinds of arrays. I am sorting Integer arrays in numerical order which I have working and I also need to sort Character arrays in alphabetical order. I am having a little trouble with sorting the Character array. My teacher wants to us to sort capital letters and he wants them to stay capital when printing the array. First I have the Character array convert everything to lower case so it sorts it properly. But how would I get the Character to go back to capital without messing up the order.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyProgram extends ConsoleProgram
{
   int[] numbers = {4, 2, 3, 1, 11, 9};
   Character[] characters = {'z', 'c', 'a', 'q', 'B', 'g'};

public void run()
{
   Arrays.sort(numbers);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));


    Arrays.sort(characters);
    for(int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
    {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(characters[i]))
        {
            characters[i] = Character.toLowerCase(characters[i]);
            Arrays.sort(characters);

        }
        System.out.println(characters[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you put in lowerCase? try turning them into String objects, and sort those alphabetically

Comment: Okay I will try that thank you for the comment.

Comment: What's wrong with `Arrays.sort(characters);`

Comment: You can't do that because on the ASCII table capital letters are lower numbers than the lowercase so it sorts the capital letters first.

Comment: So you want it to be sorted irrespective of *case*?

Comment: Yeah the letters need to be in alphabetical order no matter if they are capital or lowercase.

Comment: By the way, if you're using an `int[]` array instead of an `Integer[]` array, how come you're using a `Character[]` array instead of a `char[]` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I convert to an array of strings, sort it ignoring case then convert it back to an array of characters.

```
public char[] sortArray(char[] arr) {
    // Creating a blank string array
    String [] end = new String[arr.length];

    // Converting (char) arr array to (string) end array.
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        end[i] = "" + arr[i];
    }

    // Sorts the end array ignoring case
    Arrays.sort(end, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    // Converting (string) end array to (char) arr array.
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = end[i].charAt(0);
    }

    // Returns arr aray
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much cleaner way of doing it :

Java 8 +

```
Arrays.sort(characters, (c1, c2) -> Character.toLowerCase(c1) - Character.toLowerCase(c2));
```

Java 7 and below

```
Arrays.sort(characters, new Comparator<Character>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
        return Character.toLowerCase(c1) - Character.toLowerCase(c2);
    }

});
```

Comment: Much cleaner indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
    Character[] characters = {'z', 'c', 'a', 'q', 'B', 'g'};
    Arrays.sort(characters, (c1,c2) -> Character.compare(
            Character.toLowerCase(c1), Character.toLowerCase(c2)));
```

Comment: Nice method but note that there are a few edge cases where your method would yield different results to the standard Java String case-insensitive order. For example, consider the Greek letters σ and ς. They are both the same letter (the Greek equivalent of the letter s). σ is used at the start or in the middle of a word and ς is used at the end of a word. In Java, `"σ".compareToIgnoreCase("ς") == 0`, but your method would make them different. Another discrepancy would occur with the Turkish letters i and ı.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8 or high version,you can use Stream API to sort your array and print element in array to console:

```
    Character[] characters = {'z', 'c', 'a', 'q', 'B', 'g'};
    Stream.of(characters)
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.toString()))
            .forEach(character -> System.out.print(character + " "));
```